# How to handle collisions in Phaser

Tags: javascript, html, collision, phaser-framework

I want to make objects push away from each other in my Phaser game (arcade physics).
To do so I've tried to use the `collider` function:

```js
  let avatar = this.physics.add.sprite(
    localStorage.x ? localStorage.x*1 : 300,
    localStorage.y ? localStorage.y*1 : 300,
    "avatar",
    0
  );

let tree = this.physics.add.image(100, 0, "bigtree");
  tree.setScale(4, 4);
  tree.setImmovable();
  this.physics.add.collider(avatar, tree);
```

But I always get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.isParent')`

It looks like this is error rises during the update process as it's risen thousand times a minute…

I'm using Phaser 3

Does anyone know the answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this link might help https://phaser.discourse.group/t/solved-cannot-read-property-isparent-of-undefined/2119

Comment: @winner_joiner It sort of did… I actually just forget to put it in the update loop… Nevertheless your post helped me solve this (and actually another) problem. So if you want to get some points, make this an answer so I can approve it

Comment: since I'm not sure what exactly helped you, in the post it would be better, if you write the answer, but thank you for the offer and the information, that it was solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you have to put those collider functions in the update loop…